# Qt/C++ How does one iterate QMetaObject's properties / data types of a given Class Object?

Tags: c++, qt

In C#/Java I use reflection to read in the properties of a class.  I have made an attempt using Qt, and don't know if I'm going about solving my problem correctly.

A simple Person Class Header, note the 3 properties (id, fname, lname)

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <QObject>

class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Person(QObject *parent = 0);

    int id;

    QString fname;

    QString lname;

    /* ... 50+ more properties here */

    int getId() const;
    void setId(int value);

    QString getFname() const;
    void setFname(const QString &value);

    QString getLname() const;
    void setLname(const QString &value);

    /* ... 50+ more getter/setters here */

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

With the following code snippet, I would like to print the properties of the Person class.  The intent would be to later loop through a collection of objects and load a QMap with values depending if the class property has an assigned value.

```
Person p;
const QMetaObject *metaObj = p.metaObject();
qDebug() << "class name: " << metaObj->className();
qDebug() << "method count: " << metaObj->methodCount();
qDebug() << "property count: " << metaObj->propertyCount();
qDebug() << "ClassInfo count: " << metaObj->classInfoCount();

qDebug() << "properties: ";
for (int i = metaObj->propertyOffset(); i < metaObj->propertyCount(); ++i)
    qDebug() << metaObj->property(i).type() << " " << metaObj->property(i).typeName();
```

However, the outputs are:

```
class name:  Person
method count:  5
property count:  1
ClassInfo count:  0
Constructor count:  1
properties:
```

These numbers make no sense and no properties are displayed.

Comment: *id*, *fname*, and *lname* are class members. Qt uses the term *property* to mean something else: See [The Property System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html).

Comment: Inspectable - you need to move your comment to the Answer.  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: It's not really a complete answer (it doesn't address the *method count*, for example). If you feel like writing up an answer to your own question, this is perfectly fine (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: Updated with solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thanks  IInspectable!**

revised class property declarations to reflect Q_PROPERTY

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString id READ getId WRITE setId)
int id;

Q_PROPERTY(QString fname READ getFName WRITE setFName)
QString fname;

Q_PROPERTY(QString lname READ getLName WRITE setLName)
QString lname;
```

slight update to the object loop:

```
qDebug() << "properties: ";
for (int i = metaObj->propertyOffset(); i < metaObj->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        //qDebug() << metaObj->property(i).type() << " " << metaObj->property(i).typeName();
        qDebug() << metaObj->property(i).read(data);

    }
```

outputs are:

```
class name:  Person
method count:  5
property count:  4
ClassInfo count:  0
Constructor count:  1
properties:
QVariant(int, 12345)
QVariant(QString, "John")
QVariant(QString, "Doe")
```

Comment: Oh, bummer. I thought QMetaObject would be able to get all the fields by the default without having to decorate them with Q_PROPERTY. What a pity.

Comment: I'm learning about the property system as well, I'm curious why `Q_PROPERTY(QString id READ getId WRITE setId)` wouldn't be `Q_PROPERTY(int id READ getId WRITE setId)`. Since `id` is defined as an `int`?