# Qt listing properties of Class

Tags: c++, qt, properties, macros

I have a class (CNode)

CNode has this property

```
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName/* NOTIFY nameChanged*/)
```

Everything compiles fine...

`Question is`: How can I list all of the properties? Sure, I could create an array of property-names but that doesn't seem very space-efficient as the program has to run on 50mb of Ram.

Comment: You can do it using QMetaObject capabilities. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34362205/7705264)

Comment: thank you ;) @em2er

Comment: could you please formulate an answer and give some examples so the next person can easily find it without too much browsing? @em2er

Comment: You will still have to create a list for the model anyway, the difference is it will happen automatically rather than you having to type it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) instance of your class, that holds information about properties, signals, slots and other meta data.
Suppose we have

```
class CNode: public QObject
{
      Q_OBJECT

      Q_PROPERTY(int myInt_ READ myInt WRITE setMyInt)
      Q_PROPERTY(QString myStr_ READ myStr WRITE setMyStr)

public:
      int myInt() const {return myInt_;}
      QString myStr() const {return myStr_;}
      void setMyInt(int value) {myInt_ = value;}
      void setMyStr(const QString& value) {myStr_ = value;}

private:
      int myInt_;
      QString myStr_;
};
```

So now we can get all properties with names and values:

```
CNode* node = new CNode;
node->setMyInt(100);
node->setMyStr("Its my string");
for(int i = node->metaObject()->propertyOffset(); i < node->metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i)
{
      qDebug() << node->metaObject()->property(i).name() << node->metaObject()->property(i).read(node);
}
```

**Edit**: `propertyOffset` returns integer index at which properties of CNode starts (supposed that superclass may have its own properties). If you wish to get properties of superclasses too, you can start `i` with 0. You can find more information at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qmetaobject.html#propertyOffset.

Comment: propertyOffset() returns what? I can't find it in the doc

Comment: I put `metaObject()->property(metaObject()->propertyCount()-1).name();´ into the constructor of node, but I get an compiler-error

Comment: @ThefrenchSpeedruns provide full example please. Maybe to open new question is more appropriate for that. `CNode::CNode()
{
      qDebug() << metaObject()->property(metaObject()->propertyCount() - 1).name();
}` works for me

Comment: Ok, I just forgot to include QMetaProperty and QMetaObject